# Keil debugger exits automatically

Tags: microcontroller, debugging, keil, tm4c123g

I am using Keil uVision5 for programming TI launchpad TM4C123GXL.

Keil work perfectly fine for building and flashing the programs (examples projects of Tiva Ware,) but when I start the debug session, at first debugging mode seems to open perfectly but a second afterward it automatically shuts down.

I have the same software working fine on another PC but it is not working on my laptop.

How can I fix this bug so that I can do debugging?

It used to work fine a few months ago, but now it's not working. Have I changed some setting?

I have reinstalled Keil, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug in Keil. It is related to Keil's registry entries. The bug-fix is described here: [RegistryFix for Keil Debugger](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Volume1/Window8KeilDebuggerFix.htm)

Comment: It's created again after I deleted it. So I deleted the value of that registry  and now everything is OK.